# Make all global variables available in a function

Tags: php

My project uses a template system to put the pages together and there are many variables involved. Usually the template is loaded directly from an index file and not from within a function.

However, at the moment I'm simply making this function to display an error page:

```
function show_error($error){
    global $root;
    global $template;
    $content=$root."/includes/pages/error_page.html.php";
    include $root . $template;
    exit();
}
```

However, since the template uses many variables outside the scope of this function, it just comes up with lots of variable not found errors.

Is there a way of simply making all global variables available inside of a function? I'd rather not individually declare all possible variables inside as it would be quite tedious and because I am often adding more variables in the template.

Comment: your template should not be accessing variables outside of its scope

Comment: you might benefit from learning how to actually do some basic templating in PHP: http://chadminick.com/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `extract()` to import all globals into function scope

```
$foo = 'bar'; // global scope
function test(){
    extract($GLOBALS, EXTR_OVERWRITE, 'g'); // import with prefix to avoid mess
    echo $g_foo; // outputs: bar
}
```

Read more: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.extract.php

Answer (score 0):

If $content and $root are in global context, you can access them inside the function by adding this to the function before you use them:

```
global $content, $root;
```

Comment: Sorry I have edited my question, that is already included. It's the many other variables that the template uses which is causing the issue as I would have to declare them all.

Comment: If you are using tons and tons of global variables, you should use $GLOBALS.